# Android カスタムxmlによるキーボードの開発

Tags: android, java

Android Studioを使ってカスタムIMEを作ろうと考えています｡
以来のテンキー/qwertyレイアウトのように画面下部を占有するのではなく
iOSのAssistiveTouchや[Hero Keyboard](http://herokeyboard.com/)､[Pie Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jun.ace.piecontrol&hl=ja)のように画面上でフローティングし位置の変更やリサイズを自由に行えるキーボードを作ろうと思い[JavaScriptでモック](https://github.com/Ziggomatic/circlekey)は作ったのですが､[sdkのsoftkeyboardサンプル](https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/SoftKeyboard)を用いての開発だけでは画面上の自由な位置にキーボードを配置するのは不可能でしょうか｡アドバイスよろしくお願いします｡

Answer (score 1):

完全自由ではないですが可能です。

動かしたい該当WindowのLayoutParamsのx,yを変更することで可能です。

その他用途に応じてFlagが必要な場合がありますが下記を参照してください。
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html